# boldsymbol not working in beamer with Helvetica

Tags: beamer, fonts, bm, helvetica, boldsymbol

The title pretty much says anything. Compare the output of the two.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  $\widehat{\myvec{H}}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\begin{document}
  $\widehat{\myvec{H}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I overcome this problem in beamer?